# Error compiling when use iostream in Hello World

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

There were some errors when I compiled my program. I thought the problem lied in the g++ compiler and I tried with the Hello World program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

Then I compiled it:

```
g++ helloworld2.cpp -o helloworld2cpp
```

Then I got:

```
In file included from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/iostream:38:0,
                 from helloworld2.cpp:1:
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/c++config.h:66:39: error: #if with no expression
 #if _GLIBCXX_HAVE_ATTRIBUTE_VISIBILITY
                                       ^
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/c++config.h:211:28: error: operator '!' has no right operand
 #if ! _GLIBCXX_USE_DUAL_ABI
                            ^
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/c++config.h:220:27: error: #if with no expression
 #if _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI
                           ^
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/c++config.h:245:28: error: #if with no expression
 #if _GLIBCXX_INLINE_VERSION
                            ^
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/c++config.h:412:27: error: #if with no expression
 #if _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI
                           ^
In file included from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/iostream:38:0,
                 from helloworld2.cpp:1:
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/c++config.h:537:3: error: operator '&&' has no right operand
   && _GLIBCXX_USE_DUAL_ABI && __cpp_transactional_memory >= 201505L \
   ^~
In file included from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/iostream:38:0,
                 from helloworld2.cpp:1:
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/c++config.h:30:0: error: unterminated #ifndef
 #ifndef _GLIBCXX_CXX_CONFIG_H

In file included from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/iosfwd:38:0,
                 from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/ios:38,
                 from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/ostream:38,
                 from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/iostream:39,
                 from helloworld2.cpp:1:
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/c++config.h:30:0: error: unterminated #ifndef
 #ifndef _GLIBCXX_CXX_CONFIG_H
 
In file included from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/stringfwd.h:39:0,
                 from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/iosfwd:39,
                 from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/ios:38,
                 from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/ostream:38,
                 from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/iostream:39,
                 from helloworld2.cpp:1:
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/c++config.h:30:0: error: unterminated #ifndef
 #ifndef _GLIBCXX_CXX_CONFIG_H
 
In file included from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/memoryfwd.h:48:0,
                 from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/stringfwd.h:40,
                 from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/iosfwd:39,
                 from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/ios:38,
                 from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/ostream:38,
                 from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/iostream:39,
                 from helloworld2.cpp:1:
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/c++config.h:30:0: error: unterminated #ifndef
 #ifndef _GLIBCXX_CXX_CONFIG_H

......

In file included from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/ostream:638:0,
                 from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/iostream:39,
                 from helloworld2.cpp:1:
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/ostream.tcc:358:29: error: #if with no expression
 #if _GLIBCXX_EXTERN_TEMPLATE
                             ^
In file included from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/istream:934:0,
                 from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/iostream:40,
                 from helloworld2.cpp:1:
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/istream.tcc:1039:29: error: #if with no expression
 #if _GLIBCXX_EXTERN_TEMPLATE
                             ^
In file included from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/ios:40:0,
                 from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/ostream:38,
                 from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/iostream:39,
                 from helloworld2.cpp:1:
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/char_traits.h: In static member function 'static constexpr __gnu_cxx::char_traits<_CharT>::int_type __gnu_cxx::char_traits<_CharT>::eof()':
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/char_traits.h:135:38: error: '_GLIBCXX_STDIO_EOF' was not declared in this scope
       { return static_cast<int_type>(_GLIBCXX_STDIO_EOF); }
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/char_traits.h: In static member function 'static constexpr std::char_traits<char>::int_type std::char_traits<char>::eof()':
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/char_traits.h:317:38: error: '_GLIBCXX_STDIO_EOF' was not declared in this scope
       { return static_cast<int_type>(_GLIBCXX_STDIO_EOF); }
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/ios:42:0,
                 from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/ostream:38,
                 from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/iostream:39,
                 from helloworld2.cpp:1:
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/ios_base.h: At global scope:
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/ios_base.h:196:16: error: '_GLIBCXX_STDIO_SEEK_CUR' was not declared in this scope
       _S_cur = _GLIBCXX_STDIO_SEEK_CUR,
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/ios_base.h:197:16: error: '_GLIBCXX_STDIO_SEEK_END' was not declared in this scope
       _S_end = _GLIBCXX_STDIO_SEEK_END,
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The output of `g++ -v helloworld2.cpp` is:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0 --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --disable-multilib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.3.0 (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/cc1plus -quiet -v -D_GNU_SOURCE helloworld2.cpp -quiet -dumpbase helloworld2.cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase helloworld2 -version -o /tmp/ccS4Oxqi.s
GNU C++14 (GCC) version 6.3.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 6.3.0, GMP version 4.3.2, MPFR version 2.4.2, MPC version 0.8.1, isl version 0.15
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /public/software/compiler/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mkl/include
 .
 /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/../../../../include/c++/6.3.0
 /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/../../../../include/c++/6.3.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
 /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/../../../../include/c++/6.3.0/backward
 /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include
 /usr/local/include
 /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include
 /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/include-fixed
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++14 (GCC) version 6.3.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 6.3.0, GMP version 4.3.2, MPFR version 2.4.2, MPC version 0.8.1, isl version 0.15
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 513de03d75e1fe7e175c88abdb78989c
In file included from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/iostream:38:0,
                 from helloworld2.cpp:1:
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/c++config.h:66:39: error: #if with no expression
 #if _GLIBCXX_HAVE_ATTRIBUTE_VISIBILITY
                                       ^
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/c++config.h:211:28: error: operator '!' has no right operand
 #if ! _GLIBCXX_USE_DUAL_ABI
                            ^
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/c++config.h:220:27: error: #if with no expression
 #if _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI
                           ^
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/c++config.h:245:28: error: #if with no expression
 #if _GLIBCXX_INLINE_VERSION
                            ^
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/c++config.h:412:27: error: #if with no expression
 #if _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI
                           ^
In file included from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/iostream:38:0,
                 from helloworld2.cpp:1:
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/c++config.h:537:3: error: operator '&&' has no right operand
   && _GLIBCXX_USE_DUAL_ABI && __cpp_transactional_memory >= 201505L \
   ^~
In file included from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/iostream:38:0,
                 from helloworld2.cpp:1:
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/c++config.h:30:0: error: unterminated #ifndef
 #ifndef _GLIBCXX_CXX_CONFIG_H

In file included from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/iosfwd:38:0,
                 from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/ios:38,
                 from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/ostream:38,
                 from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/iostream:39,
                 from helloworld2.cpp:1:
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/c++config.h:30:0: error: unterminated #ifndef
 #ifndef _GLIBCXX_CXX_CONFIG_H
 
In file included from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/stringfwd.h:39:0,
                 from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/iosfwd:39,
                 from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/ios:38,
                 from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/ostream:38,
                 from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/iostream:39,
                 from helloworld2.cpp:1:
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/c++config.h:30:0: error: unterminated #ifndef
 #ifndef _GLIBCXX_CXX_CONFIG_H

......

In file included from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/ios:40:0,
                 from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/ostream:38,
                 from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/iostream:39,
                 from helloworld2.cpp:1:
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/char_traits.h: In static member function 'static constexpr __gnu_cxx::char_traits<_CharT>::int_type __gnu_cxx::char_traits<_CharT>::eof()':
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/char_traits.h:135:38: error: '_GLIBCXX_STDIO_EOF' was not declared in this scope
       { return static_cast<int_type>(_GLIBCXX_STDIO_EOF); }
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/char_traits.h: In static member function 'static constexpr std::char_traits<char>::int_type std::char_traits<char>::eof()':
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/char_traits.h:317:38: error: '_GLIBCXX_STDIO_EOF' was not declared in this scope
       { return static_cast<int_type>(_GLIBCXX_STDIO_EOF); }
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/ios:42:0,
                 from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/ostream:38,
                 from /public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/iostream:39,
                 from helloworld2.cpp:1:
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/ios_base.h: At global scope:
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/ios_base.h:196:16: error: '_GLIBCXX_STDIO_SEEK_CUR' was not declared in this scope
       _S_cur = _GLIBCXX_STDIO_SEEK_CUR,
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/include/c++/6.3.0/bits/ios_base.h:197:16: error: '_GLIBCXX_STDIO_SEEK_END' was not declared in this scope
       _S_end = _GLIBCXX_STDIO_SEEK_END,
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

My g++ version `g++ --version` is:

```
g++ (GCC) 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

The output of `type g++` is:

```
g++ is hashed (/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/bin/g++)
```

The output of `which g++` is:

```
/public/software/compiler/gcc-6.3.0/bin/g++
```

My Linux version `cat /proc/version`:

```
Linux version 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-022.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Jan 29 11:47:41 EST 2013
```

The output of `lsb_release -a` is：

```
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)
Release:        6.4
Codename:       Santiago
```

I was wondering what was wrong with my C++.

Comment: Something seems to be off with your header file. Reinstall g++

Comment: `/public/software/compiler` is an odd path. So, what linux are you using? What would `g++ -v helloworld.cpp` output? What does `type g++` and `which g++` output? `Copyright (C) 2016` so how old is your linux? What architecture are you running on?

Comment: It looks that you include header files which are not compatible to the compiler or mixed up with different versions. Reinstall! :-)BTW: 6.x.x? Really? Current version is 11.x.x.

Comment: You show helloworld.cpp but the error says helloworld2.cpp

Comment: I recommend appending `'\n'` to your output text, to ensure the output is flushed.

Comment: Hi guys, I have updated some information. Could you help me check it? Thank you.

Comment: have you tried `sudo yum install gcc`? Or in fact, just update your entire system. Just in case some other dependencies are out of date. `sudo yum update` I believe should do it.